# TortoiseHG switch back to a closed branch

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

Please can someone guide me through a process here?
I'm a bit of a newb in Mercurial so I'll post a pic to be more specific.

Here's the tree of our repo right now:

[image]

We have 2 branches: processors and extra libraries.
We created extra libraries after processors to test certain issues. Then we closed it and continue working on processors.

Now it occurred the need to change back to extra libraries in #645 to push some new stuff for testing. Is this possible now? and how can I do it with TortoiseHG?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Sorry for the silly question but I want to be very careful on this repo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed branch is usual branch, which just have some additional meta-info in branch-head.

If you want to "reopen" closed branch, you have

- Update to head's changeset (645)
- So some (needed) changes in working dir and commit: changeset 658 will be new head of active named branch, tip of repository and closed named branch will become open

Comment: So, I updated the head to 645 discarding the changes (that was the part I was afraid to proceed) and I was able to push new files on extra libraries! Thanks a lot!

Comment: To switch back to processors I have to follow the same procedure, right? (updating to 657 & discarding the changes)

Comment: @LePhleg - you can commit local changes (and rebase to the another branch, if it needed). And yes, switching between branches (any branches) is always the same thing